# jquery : one option of a select has empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<select name="category" class="tri_cat">
<option value="">classer par catégories</option>
<option value="1">label 1</option>
<option value="2">label 2</option>
<option value="9">label 3</option>
<option value="3">label 4</option>
<option value="4">label 5</option>
<option value="5">label 6</option>
<option value="6">label 7</option>
<option value="7">label 8</option>
<option value="8">label 9</option>
</select>
```

When I try to get the value of the select with jquery, everything works fine :

```
console.log($('.tri_cat').val());
```

Except for label 5 (a.k.a value 4), the log returns an empty string.

In other cases, the log returns the correct value.

Before logging the value, I check a hash in the url and change the value if one exists. It's the only moment where I'm messing with the input value:

```
$('.tri_cat').val(hash);
```

It's a total mystery for me :s

Comment: That seems suspect. It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/BrtuX/

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with the above.  Is that a copy & paste of the html for the select?

Comment: my gut tells me there is other code you haven't mentioned that is interfering with this process.

Comment: If you have multiple `.tri_cat` elements, only the value from the first one will be read. Therefore, if you change the second one, the value will come back as `''` due to reading from the first

Comment: true, i didn't tell i met this by maintaining an application, i seriously should. I posted to get some ideas of what could provoke such a behavior

Answer (score 0):

I try with this fiddle, adding a button to control when log the value:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  console.log($('.tri_cat').val());
});
```

Try it on my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CPLK2/

In my case everything working fine, for label 5 to

Comment: it was in a maintenance context (discovering code), it was an html issue, two form containing such a select were in the form, with same class and same id... In fact, the weird part was the selecting of all other values, cause when i logged html() instead of val(), i get the html of the first select.

Comment: @SupFrig It depends on exactly what selectors you were using, but yeah, that's a weird scenario.